# Fractional cointegration in R

Tags: programming, econometrics, cointegration

I'm looking for a package (or some code that anyone has written) that will help me to estimate a VECM for fractionally cointegrated series. I.e. like the `ca.jo` function in the `urca` package.

I'm aware of the `fracdiff` package in R, however this does not allow me to estimate the VECM.

Thankful for help!